# Runtime Error: Event loop is closed, When two bots with the same code run at once

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I have been making bots using discord.py, and I ran into a problem. I was running one bot, and I decided to make another. When I tested it on a new server, I got an error message saying `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed.`, but that didn't happen with the other bot, which had the exact same code as the first one, just with a different token. Why does this happen, and what should I do to fix it? here is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 261, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 225, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\26afa\Documents\GameBotDiscord\GameBot3000.py", line 24, in <module>
    client.run(token)  # recall my token was saved!
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 265, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000019F1121F430>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: Is there a line that it points to specifically? Perhaps the full error traceback would be helpful. Does the bot start up at all? Or does it error when you run a certain command?

Comment: It does not start up at all; when I run the code, it immediately gives me the error message.

Comment: Is it alright if you include the error traceback in your answer? It could point to a line which is causing this

Comment: Ok, I added the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of the error message, it's complaining about the bot's token. Make sure you added the [Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnwhe.png) from the `Bot` tab in the [developer's page](https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/me), and not the Client ID.

Also, make sure to print out the token and compare it to the one on the developer's page if you're unsure or getting it from another file etc.

If it still doesn't work, generate a new Token and use that instead.